# ¿como usar plt.xticks() para mostrar fechas(en dias) en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

tengo el problema de que pongo la fecha en el eje x pero solo se pone en una parte como la imagen
junta todo los dias al izquerda

los datos son del todo el año y quiero que se muestre dias o meses 
 [image: junta todo los dias al izquerda]

```
plt.title("sacramento")
plt.xlabel("crimenes ")
plt.ylabel("indice de crimen ")

plt.xticks(range(100),fechas,size = 'small',color = 'b',rotation = 45)

for distrito,  filas in grupos.items():
    lista = [fila[9] for fila in filas]
    promedio = [sum(lista[:i+1])/float(i+1) for i in range(len(lista)-1)]
    plt.plot(promedio ,label = "distrito"+ str(distrito))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

un ejemplo 
`fechas = [1/04/06 00:00,1/05/06 00:02,2/06/06 2:00]`

`fechas` tiene un tamaño 7857

Comment: Hola Luis, ¿la lista fechas como la obtienes y que tipo de dato contiene? Son `str`, `datetime.datetime`, `np.datetime64`, etc. Si tienes dudas mira a ver que obtienes con `print(type(fechas[0]))`. Supongo que se corresponden 1 a 1 con la lista `promedio` ¿no?

Comment: @FJSevilla son datetime y algunos son repetidos porque el promedio algunos tiene la misma fecha

Comment: Luis no termina de quedarme clara la relación de las fechas con cada promedio. ¿Cada distrito tiene sus propias fechas? es decir, ¿la fecha del primer promedio es o no igual a la fecha de los primeros promedios del resto de distritos? Ten en cuenta que aunque cambias las marcas el eje X este sigue representando enteros (0, 1, 2, ... n) que son el indice en la lista de cada promedio y no fechas. Deberías intentar explicar que estas intentado representar y que es cada variable, si pudieras aportar un ejemplo pequeño pero reproducible  seria de gran ayuda.